# Upgrade Ansible Tower - Minor upgrade

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

Anyone got a proper instruction set to upgrade Ansible Tower 3.4 to 3.6 ?
(Ansible 2.5,  Database - postgres 9.6)

Found [Ansible Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/upgrade-migration-guide/index.html) but not in details.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> **EDIT:** The original question pertained to upgrading AWX. It's been edited and now pertains to upgrading Ansible Tower. My answer below only applies to upgrading AWX.

If you used the [docker-compose installation method](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md#docker-compose) and pointed `postgres_data_dir` to a persistent directory on the host, upgrading AWX is straightforward. I deployed AWX 2.0.0 in 2018 and have upgraded it to every subsequent release (currently running 9.1.0) without issue. Below is my upgrade method which preserves all data including secrets between upgrades and does not rely on using the tower cli / awx cli tool.

**AWX path assumptions:**

Existing installation: `/opt/awx`

New release: `/tmp/awx`

**AWX inventory file assumptions:**

```
use_docker_compose=true
postgres_data_dir=/opt/postgres
docker_compose_dir=/var/lib/awx
```

**Manual upgrade process:**

- **Backup your AWX host before continuing**! Consider backing up your postgres database as well.
- [Download the new release](https://github.com/ansible/awx/releases) of AWX and unpack it to /tmp/awx
- Ensure that the **patch** package is installed on the host.
- Create a patch file containing the differences between the new and
  existing inventory files:

`diff -u /tmp/awx/installer/inventory /opt/awx/installer/inventory > /tmp/awx_inv_patch`

- Patch the new inventory file with the differences:

`patch /tmp/awx/installer/inventory < /tmp/awx_inv_patch`

- Verify that the files now match:

`diff -s /tmp/awx/installer/inventory /opt/awx/installer/inventory`

- Copy the new release directory over the existing one:

`cp -Rp /tmp/awx/* /opt/awx/`

- Edit `/var/lib/awx/docker-compose.yml` and change the version numbers 
  after `image: ansible/awx_web:` and `image: ansible/awx_task:` to match the
  new version of AWX that you're upgrading *to*.
- Stop the current AWX containers:

`cd /var/lib/awx`

`docker-compose stop`

- Run the installer:

`cd /opt/awx/inventory`

`ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml`

AWX starts the upgrade process, which usually completes within a couple minutes. I'll typically monitor the upgrade progress with `docker logs -f awx_web` until I see `RESULT 2 / OKREADY` appear.

- If everything is working as intended, I shut the containers down, pull and then recreate them using docker-compose:

`cd /var/lib/awx`

`docker-compose stop`

`docker-compose pull && docker-compose up --force-recreate -d`

- If everything is *still* working as intended, I delete `/tmp/awx` and `/tmp/awx_inv_patch`.

Comment: Thanks @jconnel, 
This is really helpful. Noted the same for AWX.

Yeah, I meant for Tower, just added AWX tag in case if anyone got an idea.

Thanks for details.

Answer (score 1):

Updgrades in AWX are not supported by ansible/redhat. Only the commercial Tower Licence allows to access scripts and procedures to do this.

From the [awx project FAQ](https://www.ansible.com/products/awx-project/faq)

> Q: Can I upgrade from one version of AWX to another?
>
> A: Direct in-place upgrades between AWX versions are not supported. It is possible to migrate data between different versions of AWX using the tower-cli tool. To migrate between different instances of AWX, please follow the instructions at https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/DATA_MIGRATION.md.

The reference link on github AWX project will teach you how to export your current data with `tower-cli` and reimport it in the new version you install. Note that all credentials are exported with blank secrets so you will have to update them with the passwords/secrets once imported.

Comment: Thanks, I meant for Ansible a Tower (sorry, thought to mention AWX)